# Passing dropdown list in a RenderPartial MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

I am wondering perhaps I am trying to achieve the impossible.  I have a button on a page that displays a partialview for adding items to another model.  This has a dropdownlist which upon further investigation returns null and hence throws up an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ProjectId'.
```

I am using a ViewBag.ProjectId in the controller

```
int userId = (int)MySqlWebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
 ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.ProjectDocuments.Where(a=>a.ProjectUserId=userId), "ProjectId", "ProjectTitle");
```

RenderPartial which should be rendered in modal popup

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_AddProjectDocument", new ProjectUno.Models.ProjectDocument());}
```

in _AddProjectDocument.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectId)
    </div>
```

Models have been set up using FKs and virtual attributes.  When I use the scafolded create view  at /ProjectDocument/Create the dropdown is populated as expected.  I will be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammadb Batineh is TempData my only option?  I read that using tempdata is not good

Comment: So your dropDown is not created? Where do you use ViewData?

Comment: I am  not using viewdata am using ViewBag but the error is a bit deceptive.  I think when the compiler finds nothing for ViewBag then It defaults to ViewData.  From research it is been stated that it is because the viewbag for the dropdown is null or empty.

Comment: check this article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use a static method in these cases.  on your controller

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDown(){
    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var data = //call the database;
    foreach(var temp in data){
        ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.Text, Value = temp.Value });
    }
    return ls
}
```

and then on your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", PathToController.GetDropDown())
```

Comment: yes.  it is the path to your controller.  projectname.controllername.getdropdown()  something like that